# Passing function that needs to display a table from the database with a foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, database, function, foreach

Im making an overview for users that are administrators on my website.

The problem i am having is that i have no clue how to pass a function like the i want it to.
I've tried searching around using arguments but nothing seemed like it would fix my problem.

The code:
I have 3 scripts (+ stylesheet) that are connected to each other

adminUsers.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ("../model/handler.php");
require_once ("../model/gui_mod.php");
echo("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../stylesheet/stylesheet.css'>");

$gui_obj = new class_gui();

$gui_obj->admin();
$gui_obj->adminUsers();
```

handler.php (this page i make the connection to the database with var $conn)

```
function admins(){
    ?>
    <table>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM admin";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchall();

            foreach($result as $row){
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

gui_mod.php - This is where i make the Gui of the page

```
function adminUsers(){
        ?>
            <html>
                <body>

                    <div class="admin_container_head_bg">
                        <div class="admin_container_head_text_one">
                            <header>Administrator</header>
                        </div>
                        <div class="admin_container_head_text_two">
                            <p>Manager</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="admin_users">
                        <div class="table_admins">

                            <?php admins(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        <?php
    }
```

I had the feeling that the problem is caused because i'm requesting a function inside another function. But i honestly have no clue so if this is false please tell me :#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either declare the connection object global or pass it into the function.

```
function admins() {
    global $conn;
    ...
```

Or:

```
function admins($conn) {
    ...
}
```

And then call by passing in the connection, like:

```
admins($conn);
```

Otherwise it's not in scope. Keep in mind you'll have to declare the connection object global from the other function or pass it in to then call `admins` from it, or you'll run into the exact same problem.